# How to plot time series by highlighting missing values in r

Tags: r, plot

I have a data frame with missing values. such as:

```
time    Value 
1       23
2       12
3       NA
4       18
5       NA
```

I want to draw the time series of the data in R and highlight the missing values by circle in the graph. I don't know how to do it. I will be happy if there is any suggestion.

I used plot command but it gives empty in the missing value place. I need to highlight the missing values by a circle.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little open-ended, here are two suggestions:

## base R

```r
plot(Value ~ time, data = quux, pch = 16)
with(subset(quux, is.na(Value)),
     points(time, rep(par("usr")[3], length(time)),
            xpd = TRUE, pch = 16, col = "red"))
```

[image: base plot with NA points as red]

## ggplot2

```r
library(ggplot2)
quux |>
  transform(isna = is.na(Value), Value = ifelse(is.na(Value), -Inf, Value)) |>
  ggplot(aes(time, Value, color = isna)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("FALSE" = "black", "TRUE" = "red")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image: ggplot2 with NA points as red]

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(time = 1:5, Value = c(23L, 12L, NA, 18L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I dont know why its not working in my case! I have a big data frame in excel. There are several columns in the data set where each columns has some missing values. I want to plot the time series by line plot where the missing values should be indicated with circle. Can you suggest?

Comment: It is often informative to reveal a sample of the real data. Try using `dput(head(quux,40))` assuming your `quux` has just the two columns and the top 40 rows demonstrates enough missingness to be representative enough.